# $\infty$-categorical enhancement of $\mathsf{D}_\mathsf{B}(\mathsf{A})$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, infinity-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry, higher-algebra

In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397942/why-is-mathsfd-qcx-the-right-notion-instead-of-mathsfd-mathsfqco/397946#comment1126632_397946), it is asked why we like to consider $\mathsf{D}_\textrm{qc}(X)$ rather than $\mathsf{D}(\mathsf{QCoh}(X)).$ Professor Cisinski answers rather convincingly that the $\infty$-categorical enhancement $\mathcal{D}_\textrm{qc}(X)$ inherits many nice features of $\mathcal{D}(\mathsf{QCoh}(X)),$ but that it also satisfies descent, and is in fact the (Zariski/fppf) sheafification of
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{Sch}&\to\mathsf{qCat}^\mathsf{st}\\
X&\mapsto\mathcal{D}(\mathsf{QCoh}(X)),
\end{align*}
where $\mathsf{qCat}^\mathsf{st}$ denotes the $\infty$-category of stable $\infty$-categories (with morphisms being the exact functors?).

Professor Cisinski also states that for an abelian category $\mathsf{A}$ and a full abelian subcategory $\mathsf{B}$ (perhaps satisfying come unlisted conditions), the derived category $\mathsf{D}_\mathsf{B}(\mathsf{A})$ of objects in $\mathsf{D}(\mathsf{A})$ whose cohomology lies in $\mathsf{B}$ admits an $\infty$-categorical enhancement $\mathcal{D}_\mathsf{B}(\mathsf{A}).$ However, I was not able to find a reference for the construction of $\mathcal{D}_\mathsf{B}(\mathsf{A})$ in the place I thought I might find it (chapter 1, section 3 of *Higher Algebra)*.

In a number of papers I've read which use $\infty$-categorical techniques, $\mathcal{D}_\textrm{qc}(X)$ is defined as
$$
\mathcal{D}_\textrm{qc}(X) := \underset{\operatorname{Spec}(A)\in\mathsf{Aff}_{/X}}{\lim}\mathcal{D}(\mathsf{Mod}_A).
$$
With this definition, it is clear that $\mathcal{D}_\textrm{qc}(X)$ is the Zariski sheafification of $X\mapsto\mathcal{D}(\mathsf{QCoh}(X)).$ However, it is not clear to me that $h\mathcal{D}_\textrm{qc}(X)\simeq\mathsf{D}_\textrm{qc}(X).$ Presumably, the general construction of $\mathcal{D}_\mathsf{B}(\mathsf{A})$ is not defined as a similar limit, so that also leaves us with showing that the general construction of $\mathcal{D}_\mathsf{B}(\mathsf{A})$ in the case of $\mathsf{B} = \mathsf{QCoh}(X)$ and $\mathsf{A} = \mathsf{Mod}_{\mathcal{O}_X}$ agrees with $\mathcal{D}_\textrm{qc}(X)$ as defined above.

So, I ask:

1. What is the general construction of the $\infty$-categorical enhancement $\mathcal{D}_\mathsf{B}(\mathsf{A})$ of $\mathsf{D}_\mathsf{B}(\mathsf{A})$ (or at least, where might I find a reference for this construction)?
2. If, as I suspect, the definition of $\mathcal{D}_\textrm{qc}(X)$ given above does not agree with this construction, how does one show that its homotopy category is indeed $\mathsf{D}_\textrm{qc}(X)$?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.5351.pdf Remark 1.2.10 might be helpful

Comment: Also, the infinity category $D_B(A)$ could be defined as the full subcategory of the category $D(A)$, which has a t-structure, consisting of objects $X$ such that $\pi_0(X[n])$ is in $B$ for all $n$.